# Plot a sequence of images with matplotlib Python

Tags: python, graphics, matplotlib, cluster-analysis

I'm implementing the kmeans clustering algorithm in Python. I would like to plot at each iteration the status (image) of the clusters quality. So, basically I have a cycle which plot at each iteration an image and I want to animate this. I don't know if I made that clear. At the moment I just use the show() command which plot the image but then I have to close it in order to continue the iteration.

So, is there some way to animate the sequence of images computed at each step?

Answer (score 4):

I tried the `ion()` method and it works fine for small amount of data, but if you have large images or images streaming in relatively quickly, this method is horrendously slow. From what I understand, `ion()` will redraw everything each time you make a change to your figure, including axes and labels, etc. Which might not be what you want.

[This thread](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/viewing-an-image-cube-sequence-with-imshow-td9873.html) shows a much nicer way of doing things

Here's a simple example that I made showing how to do this:

```
import time
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure( 1 )
ax = fig.add_subplot( 111 )
ax.set_title("My Title")

im = ax.imshow( numpy.zeros( ( 256, 256, 3 ) ) ) # Blank starting image
fig.show()
im.axes.figure.canvas.draw()

tstart = time.time()
for a in xrange( 100 ):
  data = numpy.random.random( ( 256, 256, 3 ) ) # Random image to display
  ax.set_title( str( a ) )
  im.set_data( data )
  im.axes.figure.canvas.draw()

print ( 'FPS:', 100 / ( time.time() - tstart ) )
```

I get about 30 FPS on my machine with the above code. When I run the same thing with `plt.ion()` and `ax.imshow( data )` instead of `im.axes.figure.canvas.draw()` and `im.set_data( data )`, I get around 1 FPS

Answer (score 2):

Use `pause()`. For a set of images stored in `video[t, x, y]`, this makes a simple animation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(video.shape[0]):
    plt.imshow(video[i,:,:])
    plt.pause(0.5)
```

Comment: This only shows the last image of the loop in my case

Comment: Now it works! I had to add `%matplotlib qt` to make python plot into an external window. Also this answer is refreshingly compact

Answer (score 0):

Just enable the interactive mode:

```
ion()
show()
```

And it will work. This is a little bit strange. But remember: At the end of a python script, it will close the windows. You have to call

```
ion()
show()
```

at the end of the script, if you don't want the windows to close.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an image sequence visualization utility that may be helpful. Try it out [here](https://github.com/bilylee/videofig)

Below is a example that draws a dynamic sine wave.

```
import numpy as np

def redraw_fn(f, axes):
    amp = float(f) / 3000
    f0 = 3
    t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
    s = amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f0 * t)
    if not redraw_fn.initialized:
        redraw_fn.l, = axes.plot(t, s, lw=2, color='red')
        redraw_fn.initialized = True
    else:
        redraw_fn.l.set_ydata(s)

redraw_fn.initialized = False

num_time_steps = 100
videofig(num_time_steps, redraw_fn)
```